# Icon 100x100 naming convention in iOS devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4.3

on [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) it is clearly stated that an icon for spotlight search is recommended. Specifically for the iPad retina 100x100 size in use with spotlight, which name has to be given to the icon ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spotlight: Icon-Small-50@2x.png - 100 x 100**

As seen here: [High resolution/retina display app icon file names for the new iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780134/high-resolution-retina-display-app-icon-file-names-for-the-new-ipad)

> For apps that run on devices with Retina displays, two versions of
>   each icon should be provided, with the second one being a
>   high-resolution version of the original. The names of the two icons
>   should be the same except for the inclusion of the string @2x in the
>   filename of the high-resolution image.

Answer (score 4):

From this [article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html):

> **iPhone Apps**
>
> **File Size**  |  **File Name** | **Used For** | **Required Status**
>
> 29x29    | Icon-Small.png  |   Spotlight and Settings |  Optional but recommended
>
> 50x50  | Icon-Small-50.png |  Spotlight for iPad compatibility |  Recommended if you have a Settings bundle, otherwise optional but recommended
>
> 58x58 |  Icon-Small@2x.png  | Spotlight and Settings for iPhone 4 High Resolution   Recommended if you have a Settings bundle, otherwise optional but recommended
>
> **iPad Apps**
>
> **File Size**  |  **File Name** | **Used For** | **Required Status**
>
> 50x50  | Icon-Small-50.png | Spotlight on iPad | Optional but recommended
>
> 29x29  | Icon-Small.png  | Settings on iPad | Recommended if you have a Settings bundle, otherwise optional but recommended

I didn't see a 100 x 100 file...

Anyway, hope this helps!

**---Update---**

Just found this from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) where it says:

> The @2x variant of the icon is for use on devices with Retina displays only.
>
> Spotlight | **Icon-Small-50@2x.png** | 100 x 100